# STM32F4 and HSE not ready issue with oscillator

Tags: stm32

I am suffering from the problem that the HSERDY flag of STM32F412 is always zero with 24MHz Oscillator, ECS-3225MV-240.

**Background**

I finished my first hobby PCB design. It has STM32F412 and STM32L431 with Oscillator, like this:

[image]

F412 and L431 have their own 24MHz Oscillator for HSE clock source (yellow).

L431 worked fine with the HSE clock! however, F412 did not. This does not leave the HSERDY state at zero.

I made a troubleshooting list to solve the problem:

**Is it a Oscillator problem?**

- I've measured each Oscillator output waveform. L431 is working happily, so I thought there would be some difference.
- but It's exactly the same and I couldn't find a difference:
  [image: Oscillator Output signal for STM32L431]
  [image: Oscillator Output signal for STM32F412]

**Is it a chip problem?**

- I've replaced the chip twice. but problem hasn't been solved... (and this process caused the ultimate pain in my mind and wallet!)

**Is it a PCB layout problem?**

- maybe not, L431 and F412 share exactly the same clock wiring layout. It works well on the L431, but only F421 doesn't.
- I removed the L431 that was working well without any problems and soldering the F412 on the spot. but It's still the same problem.
- my F412 schematic was here:
  [image]

**Is it a software problem?**

- I tried to initialize HSE using auto-generated code from CubeMX with latest available version of the HAL/LL driver.

```
    LL_FLASH_SetLatency(LL_FLASH_LATENCY_3);
    while (LL_FLASH_GetLatency() != LL_FLASH_LATENCY_3)
    {
    }

    LL_PWR_SetRegulVoltageScaling(LL_PWR_REGU_VOLTAGE_SCALE1);
    LL_RCC_HSE_EnableBypass();

    LL_RCC_HSE_Enable();
    while (LL_RCC_HSE_IsReady() != 1)            // <---- Stuck in here...
    {
    }
```

- the same code was generated for L431. so... I don't think this is a problem.

Errr.... I don't have much experience with PCB. I've tried this and that within my knowledge, but the problem hasn't been solved. Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: This is a standard oscillator. I was mistaken for the previous design of TCXO...

Comment: Please post the schematics.

Comment: @Justme Thank you for your feedback. I have attached the schematic of STM32F412.

Comment: The oscillator enable is controlled from MCU. Is the oscillator enabled?

Comment: @Justme Yes, when the PC15 pin is changed to Output high, the oscillator begins to output the waveform. I checked the output of the waveform using oscilloscope. you can check the screenshot of the post.

Comment: Yes but my point was, have you enabled the oscillator before you try to use it?

Comment: @Justme Yes... I'm sure.

Comment: @Justme I took a hint from your answer and return to the start point. I started investigating PCB... and found the broken pattern between the output pin of the oscillator and MCU HSE input pin. I repaired this with soldering and It's start working! thank you for helping me end my five-day nightmare.